# Can I turn my USB cable into a USB host cable by adding a Female to Female adapter?

Tags: usb

Instead of buying a USB Micro B (M) to USB A (F) cable can I use a [USB Micro B (M) to USB A (F)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GN5YKQ) with a [USB A Female to Female adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GHXTA0)?

context: I'm trying to connect usb devices to my tablet and it says I need a "USB Host cable": [http://www.archos.com/manuals/A70_EN_v1.1.htm#usb_host_cable](https://web.archive.org/web/20140824062347/http://www.archos.com/manuals/A70_EN_v1.1.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. Strictly speaking, it doesn't conform to USB specs, but neither does their official cable and that shouldn't stop you.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I tried two USB drives, a Kingston and Lexar.  Neither was recognized or showed any sign of working (no LED).   This is on Android Ice Cream Sandwhich on a Nexus S.  Did it work for you?  If so, on what hardware and OS?

Answer (score 0):

Gender changers on USB break the spec.  The USB spec is written with a strict host/peripheral or master/slave device types.  They enforce this with use of A ports on master devices and B ports on slave devices.  The wiring and behavior of A and B ports are quite distinct and not changed by a gender changer.

With USB-OTG and introduction of the micro connectors at the time there is no such thing as a micro-A port.  Instead there is a dual role micro-AB port.  That adapter is not adapting a B port to an A port, it is adapting an AB port to an A port.  The micro-AB port can accept a micro-B plug or micro-A plug, the plug is wired to let the tablet know what role the port should play.  This indication is done with a 5th contact not in the full sized A and B ports and plugs.

I realize this a very old question but it was linked to from another page I was on.  I suspect people are still seeing this like I am.  USB is not like old style serial ports in which gender changers will ease all your cable connecting burdens.  USB cables must have an A end and a B end, with very rare exceptions.  USB-C and USB-AB are dual role, or at least handle safely being connected to A and B devices.  Non-compliant adapters from fly-by-night Chinese part suppliers will not make your problems go away, they will only add to them.

I know how USB evolved created quite the mess of cables and adapters so one needs to pay attention before making a purchase.  If in doubt refer to the manual, contact the manufacturer, or check with reputable sources.  I'm seeing a lot of bad advice being repeated on StackExchange on use of noncompliant USB adapters, and this disturbs me.  Using the wrong USB adapter or cable can cause expensive, possibly irreparable, damage.  Again, USB is not like the old serial ports, USB provides a **lot** of power that can start cables on fire.  The manual specifies the adapter needed, I suggest following the manual.

What is needed here is one of two things, assuming they followed the spec on the tablet.  One option is a micro-A to B cable, with the B end sized to match your device.  The other is a micro-A to full sized A port adapter.  If the tablet did in fact use a B port to provide master, type-A port, functionality then they violated the spec, which is unfortunately quite common.  If they broke the spec then you really need to get the adapter from the manufacturer as there is no telling how they wired that port.

I know that was a bit of a rant, and tone does not translate well in the written word.  I'm trying to be stern here, not mean or insulting.  Use quality USB cables from reputable manufacturers because there's been far too many reports of damaged devices, fires, and injuries from non-compliant USB cables.  I know this can be frustrating but a failure to play by the USB rules can make things worse than just frustrating.