# otg for all usb types with usb female to female?

Tags: usb, mouse, android, usb-storage

I need an otg cable for my different mobile devices usb type c, lightning connector and usb micro b.

Can I use a usb type A female to usb type A female along with the original phone cables to connect my usb storage device, mouse, etc?

Basically, i want to use a female to female usb and the original phone cable to make otg connections.

I did see this post but besides being old, the writer talks about a different connection: [Can I turn my USB cable into a USB host cable by adding a Female to Female adapter?](https://superuser.com/questions/210453/can-i-turn-my-usb-cable-into-a-usb-host-cable-by-adding-a-female-to-female-adapt)

Thank you

Comment: Mobile phones and their ability to support OTG would be off topic here. The simple fact is that it requires actual hardware and software support by your device and is not "just" a connector gender issue.

Comment: To add to @Mokubai's comment, an OTG adapter is for the mobile device, not a PC, so it wouldn't be Type A to Type A but USB-C/micro-USB/Lightning OTG adapter to Type A female _(any peripherals would be connected to the OTG adapter's Type A female end)_; [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=otg) offers several OTG adapter options, and I believe they're all backed by MonoPrice's Lifetime Cable Warranty.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

As per [USB On-The-Go connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_On-The-Go_connectors):

> To enable Type-AB receptacles to distinguish which end of a cable is plugged in, plugs have an "ID" pin in addition to the four contacts in standard-size USB connectors. This ID pin is connected to GND in Type-A plugs, and left unconnected in Type-B plugs. Typically, a pull-up resistor in the device is used to detect the presence or absence of an ID connection.

Because this additional pin is not present on the USB-A connector, you cannot accomplish the same by adding an adapter. Without the appropriate ID “setting”, the phone will operate in “device” mode, not “host” mode.

Comment: The question's author used the wrong terminology _(Type A to Type A OTG adapters don't exist)_, as a USB-C/micro-USB/Lightning to Type A OTG adapter acts like a PC's Type A female ports, so while this answer's information is accurate, it's not applicable in the _context_ of the question asked since the OTG's Type A female end has the ID pin, just as every PC's Type A port does

Comment: ? Not sure what you mean. OP wants to use the regular data cable with a USB-A to USB-A socket/socket adapter to achieve OTG. This won’t work because the A-A adapter does _not_ have access to the ID pin.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted the author's question, reading it in a different way =]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now,  I understand why no one has done this.